# Changes csv row value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# reading the csv file
patients = pd.read_csv("partial.csv")
  
# updating the column value/data
for patient in patients.iterrows():
    cip=patient['VALOR_ID']
    new_cip = re.sub('^(\w+|)',r'FIXED_REPLACED_STRING',cip)
    patient['VALOR_ID'] = new_cip
  
# writing into the file
df.to_csv("partial-writer.csv", index=False)
  
print(df)
```

I'm getting this message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/salut/load-testing/load.py", line 28, in 
> cip=patient['VALOR_ID']
> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

**EDIT**
Form code above you can think I need to set a same fixed value to all rows.

I need to loop over "rows" and generate a random string and set it on each different "row".

Code above would be:

```
for patient in patients.iterrows():
    new_cip = generate_cip()
    patient['VALOR_ID'] = new_cip
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), but not sure about `|` in regex. Maybe should be removed it:

```
df = pd.read_csv("partial.csv")

df['VALOR_ID'] = df['VALOR_ID'].str.replace('^(\w+|)',r'FIXED_REPLACED_STRING')

#if function return scalars
df['VALOR_ID'] = df['VALOR_ID'].apply(generate_cip)

df.to_csv("partial-writer.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: You can skip the loop, and replace the entire column with that one line, in Pandas?

Comment: @ZachYoung - exactly. It was reason add first and last line of code from Q.

Comment: I need to generate a random string to be replaced. I mean, I need each "cell value" has a different value after "transformation". Could you provide a way iterating over "rows"? I'm editing post for more details. I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jordi - Can you try `df['VALOR_ID'] = df['VALOR_ID'].apply(generate_cip)` ?